# Increment and Decrement through array using modulus operator or Js

Tags: javascript, increment, modulus

I was able to figure out the how to increment through my array reading through another question. Now I cant seem to figure out how to deincrement since my value is being set back to 0. I am trying to avoid a loop.

The order I am looking to acheive is:

Increment ---- "/", "/about", "/list" <-- list is the end. Decrement is just rewinding. Decrement is just going a 1 step back each time.

```
let i = 0;    
let stuff =["/", "about","list"];

next() {
    this.props.dispatch(increaseCounter())
    i = (i+1)%stuff.length;
  }
  prev() {
    this.props.dispatch(decreaseCounter())
    i = (i-1)%stuff.length; <------This gets wonky once I reach the end of my array.
  }
```

Comment: Do you want the increment value to go: `0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2...` and the decrement `2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0...` ?

Comment: Hey Fubar, Its tied into another component. So all I am looking to do is increment: 0, 1, 2 then return nothing. decrement 2,1,0 return nothing

Comment: @user992731 For "then return nothing", just use an `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `next()` to increment `i` between `0` and `2` and `prev()` to decrement between `2` and `0` you can use the following:

```
next() {
    this.props.dispatch(increaseCounter());
    i = Math.min(i + 1, stuff.length - 1);
}

prev() {
    this.props.dispatch(decreaseCounter());
    i = Math.max(i - 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: The Increment works like a charm.  The decrement skips 1 in my array once it reaches the end. So it lands on "/list" then should go back to "about" Its currently not returning anything until the second click which lands on "/"

Comment: Sorry, typo. The second one should have been `Math.max`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `%` is that it is a remainder operator with truncated division, not a [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) one with floored division. When the divisor (`i-1`) becomes negative, so does the result. You can use

```
if (--i < 0) i = stuff.length - 1;
```

or

```
i = (i + stuff.length - 1) % stuff.length;
```

instead (which only work for input values of `i` in the expected range, though)